# Find an orthogonal basis for the subspace described by $x − y − z = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Find an orthogonal basis for the subspace described by $x − y − z = 0$.

First, find two linearly independent vectors in the span of the subspace above.

$v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

Then find the projection of $v_2$ on to $v_1$. this equals $\frac{v_2⋅v_1}{v_1⋅v_1}v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2\\ 1/2\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Now I need to find the orthogonal component. $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 1/2\\ 1/2\\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2\\ -1/2\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

Therefore, the orthogonal basis for the subspace is $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1/2\\ -1/2\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

Questions: Did I do this correctly? Do my steps make sense? Alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. You could explicitly check that

1. They are orthogonal
2. They span the space you want them to span

just to be in the safe side. Arithmetic errors can happen to anyone. Checking things is a good habit to have.

A common next step is to make basis vectors of unit length, but that would be an *orthonormal* basis, so it doesn't seem like your exercise requires that.

Comment: How do I explicitly check that they span the space I want them to space? do I check that the RREF of $\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{1}{2}&a-b\\ \:\:1&-\frac{1}{2}&a\\ \:\:0&1&-b\end{pmatrix}$ is consistent?

Comment: @not_tiger You have two bases. Check that you can express each vector in one basis using the vectors in the other.

Comment: yeah. it took me a lot longer than it should haave to figure that out. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @not_tiger Right. Checking that it fulfills and spans $x-y-z=0$ is what's actually important. I entirely forgot that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Equation of the surface is $x-y-z=0$. 
We have two independent variable here let us take them $x,y$ so we determine $z$ from this. By this you got $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix} $, Now take assume another vector which is orthogonal to it, let it be $\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\z \end{pmatrix}$ so $x.1+y.1+z.0=0$ so $x+y = 0$,(the dot product must be zero) . Also it has to satisfy $x-y-z=0$. So we get $z=-2y, x=-y$ . Here only one independent variable so it is a straight line.
So we can take this vector as $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -1\\2 \end{pmatrix} $